# Never call unbindService() method on a Service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I have scenario(for theoretical purposes):

What happens if, say, there is only one Activity that is bound to a Service and it decides to never call `unbindService()` method?

Will the Service ever get destroyed, in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the Context that bound to a service is destroyed, The OS is supposed to unbind it for you. According to Google's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services), calling unbindService() yourself is recommended because "Doing so allows the idle service to shut down", but that's not a requirement